# When i click on main menu the sub menu should highlight in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

From many days am trying this but there is no result please help me when i click on main menu sub menu should highlight in php.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cssmenu a').each(function (index) {
            console.log(this.href);
            if (this.href.trim() == window.location) {
                //check if 1st level, then below condition
                //if(this.class() != "has-parent")
                //{
                // $(this).addClass("active");
                //} 
                //if not first level, assign active to parent of this
                //if(this.class()= "has-parent")
                //{
                $(this).addClass("active");
                //}     
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .active {
        background: #4FA9E4;
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="company.php">Company</a> 
            <ul>
                <li class="has-parent"><a href="a.php">a</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="b.php">b</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="patners.php">Patners</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="c.php">c</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="d.php">d</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the relevant CSS and produce this problem in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bhandhavya/NT8M7/

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `click` event or other events you are interested, and toggle class in the event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul a').click(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('li.has-sub').find('>a').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Check the <kbd>[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/2HLCK/4/)</kbd>.

Comment: This is k but here when i click on menu total menus are highlighting but i need when i click on submenu main menu should highlight.

Comment: @user3160105 in your posted question you said ***when i click on main menu sub menu should highlight***, so what indeed do you want? Please describe your needs in detail rather than waiting for others guessing what you want.

Comment: sorry,When i click sub menu main menu should highlight

Comment: ya this is correct but page also should load,example in that program when we click on a company is highlighing that is correct but page should when we click on a,a page should open and company should highlight

Comment: So you mean that the menu item of the current page should be highlighted?